# intent activity is not working properly . Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, ddms

http://img861.imageshack.us/img861/7999/64339196.png

I don't understand what the problem is ...

I created so many java and xml file , but never faced this problem ...

in DDMS there is following error ....

http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/352/83236788.png

thanks...

Comment: increase your aceept rate!!! tick some right below answer...its very useful for answers

Answer (score 1):

if you have `Listview` in layout change it ...

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"....></ListView>
```

if NO,

Than `extends Activity`

**instead of**

`extends ListActivity`

Answer (score 0):

in the image you provided there is no listView but in some xml file you have listview just change the id of that listView.

In the XML file no listview. just change extends ListActivity to extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The XML layout file for your [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) must contain a ListView with

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

when I created my class I am going to use that for listing the items ... that is I prepare that class to work for ListView ...

so I extends the ListView .. in my class , in manifest file  the class war regestared as ListActivity..

but then , I change my hirarchy , and I don't use the listView in the same class ... but  I forget to extends Activity instead of ListActivity ..

that was creating  a problem .....

thanks for help....